# Custom Content Entity Type: links annotation

Tags: entities

I created a Custom Content Entity Type with all the basic CRUD operations. It is working but I do not understand how the links work in the entity annotation and therefore not why they are necessary.

My annotation:

```
/**
* @ContentEntityType(
*   id = "myent",
*   label = @Translation("My entity"),
*   handlers = {
*     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
*     "list_builder" = "Drupal\myent\Controller\MyentListBuilder",
*     "form" = {
*       "add" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm",
*       "edit" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm",
*       "delete" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityDeleteForm",
*     },
*     "access" = "Drupal\myent\ContactAccessControlHandler",
*   },
*   base_table = "myent",
*   entity_keys = {
*     "id" = "id",
*     "uuid" = "uuid",
*   },
*   links = {
*     "edit-form" = "/",
*     "delete-form" = "/",
*   },
* )
*/
```

As you can see I just inserted the necessary slash at the links section. The actual routes to the operations have to be defined in the "myent.routing.yml" no matter what so I do not see why I should write them again in the annotation.

If I remove the links section completely the operations are gone too. So I have to write the links section in the annotation even though they have no additional information for the operations.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Years too late but just in case anyone else comes across this issue, I have figured out the answer after much searching.

According to [this section](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/creating-a-content-entity-type-in-drupal-8#s-srccontactlistbuilderphp) in the docs, the links defined in the `@ContentEntityType` annotation are used in the list builder class (defined by `list_builder`) to automatically add an 'Operations' dropdown with all of the links to the list.

This will work as long as you keep the parent method in the return statement of `returnHeader()`:

`return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);`

Changing this to `return $row;` would render the links section in the annotation useless.